# Pandas finding index of string in one column in a df in a list of strings in another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| id | tag | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Lorem | 34 |
| 123 | Ipsum | 12 |
| 456 | Ipsum | 10 |
| 456 | Dolor | 2 |

And another data frame that looks like this:

| id | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | ['Ipsum','Lorem'] |
| 456 | ['Lorem', 'Dolor'] |

I need to find the index of each tag in df one in the list of tags in df two.
So the new df one would look like:

| id | tag | cnt | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Lorem | 34 | 2 |
| 123 | Ipsum | 12 | 1 |
| 456 | Ipsum | 10 |  |
| 456 | Dolor | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with `rename` for possible add `Rank` column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and append it to `df1` by left join:

```
df = df2.explode('tags').rename(columns={'tags':'tag'})
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1)

df = df1.merge(df, how='left')

print (df)
    id    tag  cnt  Rank
0  123  Lorem   34   2.0
1  123  Ipsum   12   1.0
2  456  Ipsum   10   NaN
3  456  Dolor    2   2.0

df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].astype('Int64')
print (df)
    id    tag  cnt  Rank
0  123  Lorem   34     2
1  123  Ipsum   12     1
2  456  Ipsum   10  <NA>
3  456  Dolor    2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a simple lambda function as follows:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
df['Rank'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.tags.index(x.tag)+1 if x.tag in x.tags else np.nan, axis=1).astype('Int64')
```

Resultant dataframe will look like this:

```
     id   tag  cnt            tags  Rank
0   123 Lorem   34  [Ipsum, Lorem]  2
1   123 Ipsum   12  [Ipsum, Lorem]  1
2   456 Ipsum   10  [Lorem, Dolor]  <NA>
3   456 Dolor   2   [Lorem, Dolor]  2
```

drop the tags column if you want with:

```
df.drop(columns = ['tags'])
```

and resultant dataframe looks like:

```
     id   tag  cnt  Rank
0   123 Lorem   34  2
1   123 Ipsum   12  1
2   456 Ipsum   10  <NA>
3   456 Dolor   2   2
```